# Removing last word from FOREACH loop

Tags: php, foreach

I'm building a basic function, which builds out Mysql WHERE clauses based on how many are in the array.

```
$array = array('id' => '3', 'name' => 'roger'); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ";

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $sql .= $k . ' = ' . $v . ' AND ';
}
```

which will output

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 3 AND name = roger AND`

However obviously I don't want that last AND, how do I go about removing it from the string?

Thanks

Comment: Will $array always be populated in a way that precludes SQL injection?  Won't you need quotes around roger in the output?

Comment: For the sake of making the question succinct, I didn't include security measures, obviously all data before entered into the database will be checked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do

```
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -5);
```

But perhaps the more elegant solution is

```
$array = array('id' => '3', 'name' => 'roger'); 
$clauses = array();

foreach ($array as $k => $v)
    $clauses[] = $k . ' = ' . $v;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $clauses);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array('id' => '3', 'name' => 'roger'); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ";

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $sql .= $k . ' = ' . $v . ' AND ';
}

$sql = substr(trim($sql), 0, -3);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1=1 "; 
// add "AND x=y" for every pair of key, value pair in the array.    
foreach ($array as $k => $v) 
    $sql .= ' AND ' . $k . ' = ' . $v;
```

I've added a `1=1` to the `where` clause so that your query will be **valid** even if the array `$array` is **empty**.

Answer (score 0):

`$sql = trim($sql, ' AND ');`

Comment: `trim()` trims each of the characters A/N/D/space -- not the full string in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Reformulate the question. You're trying to put an AND after every clause except the last. It would be easier to put an AND before every clause except the first.

```
$first = true;
foreach ($array as $k => v) {
    if (!$first) $sql .= ' AND ';
    $first = false;
    sql .= $k . ' = ' . $v;
}
```

Maybe not the easiest way in this case (other people mentioned using substr). However, I've found it a good tool to remember in general for situations like this.